# Expected value of random matrix

Tags: statistics, expectation, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a random matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ a matrix composed of constants. Is it possible to take $\mathbf{B}$ out of the expected value: $E\{\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{BA}\}$.

I tried with simulation and it looks like $E\{\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{BA}\}\neq \mathbf{B}E\{\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{A}\}$.

Comment: Already for deterministic matrices $A$ and $B$, $A^HBA$ and $BA^HA$ do not coincide in general, so why would this suddenly become true when $A$ is random?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. This is easy to see because if you degenerate your density function for the random matrices so that $A = A_0$ always, then your equation is clearly invalid because matrices do not commute.